# Are there any path-connected sets (of $\Bbb R^2$) that guarantee two or more fixed points for any continuous bijections mapping them onto themselves?

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

We know by Brouwer‘s fixed-point theorem that any continuous bijection mapping the closed unit circle to itself must have a fixed point.

**My question**: are there any path-connected sets (preferably subsets of $\mathbb R^2$) that guarantee *two or more* fixed points for any continuous bijections mapping them onto themselves?

The reason I‘m imposing the path-connectedness restriction is that it‘s easy to come up with a “trivial” example by taking the union of two non-homeomorphic sets with the fixed-point property (such as the union of $[0,1]$ with the closed unit circle).

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Try the union of the unit circle and the interval $[1,2]$ on the $x$ axis.  Any homeomorphism of this must fix $1$ and $2$.

[image]

Comment: Beat me to it by just a few seconds!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ah, cool. I suppose if we wanted to make a space with $n$ fixed points, we could make something star-shaped and “glue” a different object to each point of the star, so that none of them can be mapped on to each other.